# I have a confusion about whether my "GPU" is working on this my environment or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

when I run this it shows in the result "True". when you look at my output

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\vinot\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe C:/Users/vinot/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/Face_Emotion_Recognition.py
2021-01-14 18:16:51.449435: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I run this code to check my GPU is working in this environment it shows "false"

Output:

```
C:\Users\vinot\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe C:/Users/vinot/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/Face_Emotion_Recognition.py
2021-01-14 19:26:58.943642: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/vinot/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/Face_Emotion_Recognition.py:41: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-01-14 19:27:00.780107: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-14 19:27:00.782485: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.815146: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-14 19:27:00.815337: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.821246: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.821336: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.824322: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.825471: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.826226: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-01-14 19:27:00.828651: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.829411: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-14 19:27:00.829487: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
False
2021-01-14 19:27:00.935759: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 19:27:00.935841: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-01-14 19:27:00.935888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-01-14 19:27:00.935940: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following lines of code and check

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

You will see the output below if your GPU is up and running:

`Num GPUs Available:  1`